# Conan error: Incompatible requirements obtained in different evaluations of 'requirements'

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract, package-managers, conan

Greetings to my C++ heroes,

I am trying to use [Conan](https://conan.io/) package manager to build dependencies of my C++ application (specifically libraries OpenCV and Tesseract). My conanfile.txt looks like this:

```
[requires]
opencv/4.5.1
tesseract/4.1.1

[generators]
cmake
```

When I run `conan install ../src --build=missing` command in my build directory I get following error:

```
leptonica/1.80.0: Downloaded recipe revision 0
WARN: libtiff/4.1.0: requirement libwebp/1.1.0 overridden by leptonica/1.80.0 to libwebp/1.0.3 
ERROR: libtiff/4.1.0: Incompatible requirements obtained in different evaluations of 'requirements'
    Previous requirements: [zlib/1.2.11, xz_utils/5.2.5, libjpeg/9d, jbig/20160605, zstd/1.4.8, libwebp/1.1.0]
    New requirements: [zlib/1.2.11, xz_utils/5.2.5, libjpeg/9d, jbig/20160605, zstd/1.4.8, libwebp/1.0.3]
```

I am not sure what this error means and it is quite "ungoogleable" for me. I will be very thankful for your help. Even if it will be the recommendation of another C++ packaging system. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a version conflict :

> WARN: libtiff/4.1.0: requirement libwebp/1.1.0 overridden by leptonica/1.80.0 to libwebp/1.0.3

`libtiff` wants `libwebp/1.1.0`, but `leptonica` asks for `libwebp/1.0.3`

Conan will not solve it for you, because it could create a different behavior accord `libwebp` version. So it raises:

> ERROR: libtiff/4.1.0: Incompatible requirements obtained in different evaluations of 'requirements'

You have to decide which version you want, and put it explicitly in your `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
opencv/4.5.1
tesseract/4.1.1
libwebp/1.1.0

[generators]
cmake
```

In this case I used `libwebp/1.1.0`. Conan will warn me about, but it will use my choice:

```
WARN: leptonica/1.80.0: requirement libwebp/1.0.3 overridden by tesseract/4.1.1 to libwebp/1.1.0
```

As Python karma says: "explicit is better than implicit". Conan follows that rule.

Comment: What a simple solution (facepalm)! It is working now, thank you! Just from curiosity. Why can not Conan build both versions of libwebp library for litbtiff and leptonica separately?

Comment: They are separated, but each library is a package followed by a version. What occurred here is that libwebp version is not aligned. I'll open a PR forcing 1.1.0 for both.